# Cluster method with binary variable

Tags: r, clustering, binary, numerical

I need to do a cluster analysis for the following variables:

```
Trickquestion answer: Good/Wrong
count variable : range 0-9
time in minutes
count variable 
Number of observations: 3300
```

Since I am new to cluster algorithms I'm struggling with choosing the best cluster algorithm. I have read about the following methods:

- k prototypes
- k means with Gower's distance
- PAM algorithm.

For the cluster analysis I need to use R.

Can someone give advice about which methods suits the data best. Since I'm studying mathematics I need to give a full mathematical explanation, so a blackbox algorithm is not an option. Tips were I can find Mathematical information about the algorithms are also welcome.

Comment: That sounds more like a regression task to me than clustering. **What do you expect the result to *mean*?**

Comment: I need to get different types of respondents who responded to my survey. For example serious and not serious respondents or fast/slow respondents.

Comment: Well, I would then suggest that you define "fast" and "slow", or some quality criterion relevant for your task for the computer to find. Because otherwise you may well get random clusters...

Comment: So you suggets that I should make the numerical variable time measured in minutes categorical and mark the times as fast, "normal" and slow?

Comment: No. I suggest you first formalize your problem. Define "fast".